# Size of UIImage prepared from downloaded NSData shows 0,0 even though data length is >0

Tags: iphone, ios

On server an image is uploaded which is either jpeg, bmp or png.

When the image is downloaded then  NSData shows its length to be > 0 like 173803 etc.

However, when I make UIImage out of this data via the following method and check its size then it comes 0,0.

```
UIImage *receivedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:receivedNSData];
NSLog(@"Image.size = %@",[NSValue valueWithCGSize:receivedImage.size].description]);

//output of log
// Image.size = NSSize{0,0}
```

ImageView also doesn't display the image, when set on it. Other images locally converted to NSData and then back to UIImage will display in the imageView.

Can anyone suggest me a solution to this ?

Edit 1 : Yes, I am receiving the data properly. I am getting data.length to be greater than zero like 1789938, etc. as I mentioned above initially.

Comment: It seems that the data is corrupted.

Comment: I bet receivedImage is nil.

Comment: Are you really receiving an image there? Try displaying it in an `UIImageView`. Otherwise just for curiosity try to print the data as a string, let's see what it contains. `NSString* newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[theData bytes]];`

Comment: Yes, I am receiving value in data. When I print data.length then it shows greater than zero value. i.e. something like 1788293, etc.

Comment: Check to see if your image object is nil: `NSLog(@"The image: %@",receivedImage);`

Comment: Thanks all.. and Javier Thanks!!, I worked on your response and checked that server was sending some other data than the png image. This was happening, because the png image was not getting located on server.